# isomorphism of algebric torus

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $D_n=(\mathbb{C}^{\times})^n$ (an algebric torus of rank $n$). Assuming $D_k$ is isomorphic to $D_n$ as an algebric group. Prove that $k=n$.

So far, I managed to understand (not prove yet though) that the given group isomorphism induces a surjective algebra homomorphism from [$D_k$] onto [$D_n$]. 
I think it's possible to obtain a polynomal relation of the form $x_nf(x_1,...,x_k)= g(x_1,...,x_k)$ and that implies $n<k$ or $n=k$.

Again, those are just speculations. I couldn't find a way to prove that throughly, and would appreciate help proving it completely.

Comment: I'm thinking in a differential geometry kind of way, but honestly it's just an idea I'm throwing here, I don't know how the details could work ; does a morphism of algebraic groups induce a morphism on the tangent spaces at each point? Perhaps an isomorphism of the groups would give you an isomorphism at the tangent spaces and then you use a dimensionality-for-vector-spaces argument.

Comment: I think it should work on purely algebraic level. Isn't it enough to observe that, since in that case $D_n$, $D_k$ have the same number of order $2$ elements, it follows that $n=k$?